# Split dictionary field

Tags: python, sql-server, dictionary, split

I've managed to figure out how to run a SQL query to display information. I need to keep the data in the same form as the db tables, so I think I should be using a dictionary. So far, my fields are ID and Name, my print looks like this:

```
[{'ID': '123', 'Name': 'ROBERTSON*ROBERT'}, {'ID': '456', 'Name': 'MICHAELS*MIKE'}, {'ID': '789', 'Name': 'KRISTENSEN*KRISTEN'}, ...]
```

First, am I appropriately using dictionary?

Next, I need to split the Name field based on the `*` delimiter. For example:

Before:

```
{'ID': '789', 'Name': 'KRISTENSEN*KRISTEN'}
```

After:

```
{'ID': '789', 'LastName': 'KRISTENSEN', 'FirstName': 'KRISTEN'}
```

I've tested out a few things of code I've found but keep hitting roadblocks. I've used this to create my dictionary, I'm wondering if I include a split in this line to reduce a step?

```
query = [dict(zip(['ID', 'Name'],row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: Probably not helping you but if possible I feel like the best approach would be to change your DB to have a LastName and FirstName field.

Comment: if it was only that easy @bouletta :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like so maybe:

```
query = [dict(zip(['ID', 'FirstName', 'LastName'], row[:1] + row[1].split('*'))) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple`

Answer (score 0):

**If all entries have a name split by an asterix**

A solution in two steps. Once you've retrieved your current results :

```
a = [{'ID': '123', 'Name': 'ROBERTSON*ROBERT'}, {'ID': '456', 'Name': 'MICHAELS*MIKE'}, {'ID': '789', 'Name': 'KRISTENSEN*KRISTEN'}] 

result = [{'ID' : entry['ID'], 'LastName' : entry['Name'].split('*')[0], 'FirstName' : entry['Name'].split('*')[1]} for entry in a]
```

now if you print result :

```
[{'FirstName': 'ROBERT', 'ID': '123', 'LastName': 'ROBERTSON'},
 {'FirstName': 'MIKE', 'ID': '456', 'LastName': 'MICHAELS'},
 {'FirstName': 'KRISTEN', 'ID': '789', 'LastName': 'KRISTENSEN'}]
```

**Otherwise (assuming that the field 'Name' is at least populated)**

```
results = []

for entry in a:
    name = entry['Name'].split('*')

    result = dict(ID = entry['ID'], LastName = name[0])

    if len(name) > 1:
        result['FirstName'] = name[1]

    results.append(result)
```

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: It works on my example, it would fail if one of your entries does not have a FirstName/LastName separated by a `*`

Comment: There is always a way around :). But how do you want this case to be handled? Only a last name and nothing stored in FirstName?

Comment: I edited my answer which will behave as before and in the case without `*` the full Name will be stored in LastName and FirstName will not exist. If you want it to exist then you can add an `else`statement and put an empty string in it. You can also use `try` `except` statements instead of if/else but it might be a bit overkill.

Comment: Thank you @bouletta.  This worked great!  No errors, but I only get one record printed `{'ID': '123', 'LastName': 'SMITH', 'FirstName': 'ROBERT'}`

Comment: Figured it out, just needed a loop #newbie.

Answer (score 0):

```
db_dict = {'ID': '789', 'Name': 'KRISTENSEN*KRISTEN'}
name = db_dict['Name']

def split_name(name):
    for index, char in enumerate(name):
        if char == '*':
            position = index

    last_name = name[:position]
    first_name = name[position + 1:]

    return {'LastName':last_name, 'FirstName':first_name}

new_db_dict = {db_dict.keys()[0] : db_dict.values()[0]}
new_db_dict.update(split_name(name))
print new_db_dict
```

Comment: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: i can execute this block of code without getting any error :/

Comment: Perhaps it's because some of them don't have an asterisk? Any way around that?

Answer (score 0):

First, while your use of dictionaries is valid I recommend using namedtuples for representing fixed structures with named fields

```
   from collections import namedtuple
   # structure class factory
   Person = namedtuple("Person", ("id", "name"))
   people = [ Person('123', 'ROBERTSON*ROBERT'), Person('456','MICHAELS*MIKE'), Person('789', 'KRISTENSEN*KRISTEN')]
   # different structure
   PersonName = namedtuple("Person", ("id", "first", "last"))
   # structure transformation
   def person_to_personname(person):
       """Transform Person -> PersonName"""
       names = person.name.split('*')
       if len(names) < 2:  # depends on your defaults
            last = names[0]
            first = ''
       else:  # assumes first field is last name
            last, first = names[:2]  # even if other names present, takes first two
       return PersonName(person.id, first, last)
   people_names = [person_to_personname(person) for person in people]
```